# How can I temporarily adhere plastic conduit to a brick wall?

Tags: brick, adhesive, security, temporary

I am putting up an IP camera on my front porch, using Wifi for data and an extension cord to a nearby outdoor power outlet. I have put the power cord into a cheap round 3/4" plastic conduit. The conduit has an adhesive backing on it. It turns out the conduit's instructions to "use only on a smooth surface" were words of wisdom, because after a day of adhering to my brick wall, it fell off (almost taking the camera with it). So I'm looking for a more permanent solution than tape, but less permanent/damaging than epoxy or screws. I want to be able to move the conduit in case I move the camera (which has a DIY movable magnetic mount which nevertheless was able to hold up the camera, the power cord, and the conduit :P).

According to https://www.hunker.com/12003687/what-adheres-to-brick my best option may be hot glue (which I figure can be peeled off the brick), but I figured I'd ask here for more options.

The final/current result:
[image]

Comment: Screws aren't permanent...

Comment: But the holes are. :) I guess (but don't have experience) that it'd be far easier to peel off a strip of hot glue than repair screw holes.

Comment: Maybe try some exterior mounting tape?  I'd bet that the adhesive backing isn't meant for exterior use.  3M makes one that's gray with red backing strips on it, and it sticks to pretty much everything.

Comment: Do you know whether a mounting tape will leave a visible residue on the brick if I decide to move the conduit?

Comment: Hot glue will leave residue that would be almost impossible to get out of the pores. Conduit supported at 6-8 foot intervals would only have a few small holes.

Comment: Weird. The comments about silicone caulk have been deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some [3M Extreme mounting tape http://amzn.to/2h7cIi6](http://amzn.to/2h7cIi6)
If there is any leftover tape on the wall when you remove it, use some adhesive remover on it.

The other option would be to attach some legs on the pipe so that it can be physically supported by the ground. Or wire/rope it to anything that protrudes from the brick wall.

Comment: I went with this approach (although used regular instead of extreme strength) because the adhesive remover seems the easiest way. I appreciate the warnings from others about hot glue and silicone caulk being impossible to remove from the brick pores!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a porch, so tack-it to the ceiling or hang it from the ceiling with very few screws. Maybe, just laying the conduit on top of a doorway and window with just a few nails to keep it from rolling off. I might be inclined to agree with the hot glue for a very temporary situation.

However, if temporary means a few months, I'd go for very fine nails. You'd drill into the mortar joints (only) and nail in 1/32" nails to leave unnoticeable pin-holes. Even 1/8" nail holes would be very easily finger-patched. However, there's always Duct Tape and that will work for a little while.